# How to force attach an app to android market?

Tags: java, android

When we install an app (apk file) directly via file, that app is not associated to the market, so does not appear as "installed".

Titanium Backup as an option to force attach to market, which works very well.

My question is: anyone knows how can I do something similar? I want to develop an app just to correct those associations.

Comment: You could email the developer of Titanium Backup. They may or may not be willing to share the information, but it can't hurt to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do it, but my guess would be to pull the market apk from your device, then change the extension to .zip and extract the files. Then use dex2jar to change it to a jar file, then use http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui to read the jar file.

And you could look through that to see how the market does it's links. Then somehow, you might be able to mimic what the market does.

Hopefully somebody comes up with a better answer than mine, because I don't know if my approach would work, and it would take a decent amount of effort, but hope this helps if noone else can give anything better.

Comment: I appreciate anyway your effort.

Comment: The market links are probably stored in a file in the shared preferences. So, if you have a rooted phone, you could browse to find the Market's shared prefs (/data/app, I think), and then see how it associates links. Again, this is a guess. I don't really know.